# Using JPAContainer in a project with Grails and Vaadin?

Tags: grails, jpa, groovy, grails-orm, vaadin

I'm using Vaadin + Grails with the Vaadin plugin (vaadinongrails.com). I'd like to use the JPAContainer in my code, can't figure out exactly how to. In BuildConfig.groovy, I've added

```
compile "com.vaadin:vaadin-archetype-jpacontainer:2.0.0"
```

in the "dependencies" section. This seems to work, as when running the project I see that JPAContainer is downloaded. However, if I try to use it in my project, I get

```
Compilation error: startup failed:
ui/views/AdminTableView.groovy: 24: unable to resolve class JPAContainer 
 @ line 24, column 22.
           JPAContainer container = new JPAContainer()
                        ^

ui/views/AdminTableView.groovy: 24: unable to resolve class JPAContainer 
 @ line 24, column 34.
           JPAContainer container = new JPAContainer()
                                    ^
```

Any help making this work is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: shouldn't groovyt complain about this on the import and not in code?

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't able to get this working via BuildConfig.groovy, but manually downloading into /lib did the trick. However, be warned...unless you've manually changed your Grails project to use JPA instead of Hibernate, this plugin will do you no good.